# Multifield component in AEM - values are not saved

Tags: java, xml, components, aem

I'm trying to do **multifield** component here. When I enter values in fields, they are present on page and everything works fine. When I reopen component to edit existing data, it's empty like there were no values entered (they still appear on site) at all.
Here is code from my dialog.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          jcr:title="Multifield TouchUI Component"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
          helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Text">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <fieldset
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        jcr:title="Footer"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset">
                        <layout
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <column
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <dashboard
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                        fieldDescription="Enter Headline"
                                        fieldLabel="Headline"
                                        name="./headline"/>
                                    <groups
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield"
                                        class="full-width"
                                        fieldDescription="Click '+' to add a new page"
                                        fieldLabel="Groups">
                                        <field
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                                            eaem-nested=""
                                            name="./groups">
                                            <layout
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                                                method="absolute"/>
                                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                <column
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                                                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                        <country
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                            fieldDescription="Enter headline of this group"
                                                            fieldLabel="Headline"
                                                            name="./headline"/>
                                                        <states
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield"
                                                            class="full-width"
                                                            fieldDescription="Click '+' to add a new page"
                                                            fieldLabel="Sites">
                                                            <field
                                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                                                                name="./sites">
                                                                <layout
                                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                                                                    method="absolute"/>
                                                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                                    <column
                                                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                                                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                                            <state
                                                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                                                fieldDescription="Enter name of specific site"
                                                                                fieldLabel="Site Name"
                                                                                name="./site"/>
                                                                            <path
                                                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                                                                fieldDescription="Select Path"
                                                                                fieldLabel="Path"
                                                                                name="./path"
                                                                                rootPath="/content"/>
                                                                        </items>
                                                                    </column>
                                                                </items>
                                                            </field>
                                                        </states>
                                                    </items>
                                                </column>
                                            </items>
                                        </field>
                                    </groups>
                                </items>
                            </column>
                        </items>
                    </fieldset>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

I know that there are some solutions using *widgets, xtype and ext.js* (ClassicUI), but I want to do it with **granite/coral** (TouchUI). As I researched the problem is that I should save values from every field as **child nodes**, but I do not understand how because examples are (as I noticed) same as code provided above.

If there is no help with this example, I would also be grateful if someone share their solution of **multifield** component that actually saves content author's input.

Also, if someone think that there is no such option in **TouchUI**, feel free to leave comment although that makes no sense.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't even know is this possible because there's nothing about it in documentation, but it should be a normal feature and I saw people having problems with it, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with Multifields, and the only fix I found was using the Multifield of components/**coral**/foundation and adding only fields of the same group inside the multifield.

Try with this:

```
<sites
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
        class="full-width"
        composite="{Boolean}true"
        fieldDescription="Click '+' to add a new page"
        fieldLabel="Sites">
    <field
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container"
            name="./sites">
        <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                method="absolute"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <state
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                            fieldLabel="Site"
                            fieldDescription="Enter name of specific site"
                            name="./site"/>
                    <path
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                            fieldLabel="Path"
                            fieldDescription="Select Path"
                            name="./path"/>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </field>
</sociallist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same (or similar) issue just today. For me, it turned out I needed to add the `composite="{Boolean}true"` property to my multifield. A composite multilfield can handle multiple fields within a field set.

So using your code as an example:

```
<states
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield"
    class="full-width"
    fieldDescription="Click '+' to add a new page"
    fieldLabel="Sites"
    composite="{Boolean}true">
```

This [post](https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/08/24/using-sling-models-with-nested-composite-mulitifields-in-aem-6-3/) explains it well